# what code should be in upload.php for jquery swfupload?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, swfupload

I just started using the jquery swfupload plugin and I have everything working besides the upload part... I don't know what to put in the upload.php file.

I get the error: Alert: {"name":"","type":"","size":""}; File: mayday-parade.png

upload.php originally had the code:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
echo '{"name":"'.$file['name'].'","type":"'.$file['type'].'","size":"'.$file['size'].'"}';
```

obviously this doesn't work but i added the following:

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/band_photos/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo 'file exists';
} else {
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {              
        echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}   
}
```

I can't seem to find out what i'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the the **file_post_name** in SWFUpload's settings to "**file**"?

If not, `$_FILES['file']` will not return anything, because the default-name is **Filedata** , so use `$_FILES['Filedata']` instead.

Comment: THanks that was it! BTW, do you know how to set file permissions to work only for people who are logged in that way it doesn't have to be available to the world? if not no biggie.

Comment: You can add custom  parameters that will be sended with the request. So if you e.g. send the session-ID of the user you can determine if he is logged and if not just exit the PHP-script. I cant find any documentation about this, but take a look at http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/ and search for **setPostParams** , there is an example inside a user-comment.